# How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am interested in discussing methods for using `stringstream` to parse a line with multiple types. I would begin by looking at the following line:

```
"2.832 1.3067 nana 1.678"
```

Now lets assume I have a long line that has multiple `strings` and `doubles`. The obvious way to solve this is to tokenize the string and then check converting each one. I am interested in skipping this second step and using `stringstream` directly to only find the numbers.

I figured a good way to approach this would be to read through the string and check if the `failbit` has been set, which it will if I try to parse a string into a double.

Say I have the following code:

```
string a("2.832 1.3067 nana 1.678");

 stringstream parser;
 parser.str(a);

 for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
 {
     double b;
     parser >> b;
     if (parser.fail())
     {
         std::cout << "Failed!" << std::endl;
         parser.clear();
     }
     std::cout << b << std::endl;
 }
```

It will print out the following:

```
2.832
1.3067
Failed!
0
Failed!
0
```

I am not surprised that it fails to parse a string, but **what is happening internally such that it fails to clear its `failbit` and parse the next number?**

Comment: Check my answer here please: [c++ moving to next element in a file.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24501035/1413395). I think it's relevant.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ahhh, ok so it gets stuck on the first fail.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have un-deleted at your request. After your suggested post I was pretty sure it was a duplicate. But if you would like to add an answer that would be great.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think that is reasonably simple right. I am doing a for loop and only reading 4 times because i know what length it should be. If it fails to parse the string and so it doesnt move on then it will just fail to parse it again. Using the code in your suggested answer provides the result: `2.832
1.3067
Failed!
0
1.678`

Comment: I'm afraid I have sent so many questions containing `!istream::eof()` being closed as duplicates unnecessarily. Waiting until someone finds the _real complete_ dupe for this one. THX a lot for your effort @Ben! I think this is a good starting point for a canonical answer of a FAQ.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following code works well to skip the *bad word* and collect the valid `double` values

```
istringstream iss("2.832 1.3067 nana 1.678");
double num = 0;
while(iss >> num || !iss.eof()) {
    if(iss.fail()) {
        iss.clear();
        string dummy;
        iss >> dummy;
        continue;
    }
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Here's a [fully working sample](http://ideone.com/BhVxSp).

---

Your sample almost got it right, it was just missing to consume the invalid input field from the stream after detecting it's wrong format

```
 if (parser.fail()) {
     std::cout << "Failed!" << std::endl;
     parser.clear();
     string dummy;
     parser >> dummy;
 }
```

In your case the extraction will try to read again from `"nana"` for the last iteration, hence the last two lines in the output.

Also note the trickery about `iostream::fail()` and how to actually test for `iostream::eof()` in my 1st sample. [There's a well known Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong), why simple testing for EOF as a loop condition is considered wrong. And it answers well, how to break the input loop when unexpected/invalid values were encountered. But just how to skip/ignore invalid input fields isn't explained there (and wasn't asked for).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I did immediately after you linked that answer for that other question. Excellent and quick work! +1

Answer (score 5):

Few minor differences to πάντα ῥεῖ's answer - makes it also handle e.g. negative number representations etc., as well as being - IMHO - a little simpler to read.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("2.832 1.3067 nana1.678 x-1E2 xxx.05 meh.ugh");
    double num = 0;
    for (; iss; )
        if (iss >> num)
            std::cout << num << '\n';
        else if (!iss.eof())
        {
            iss.clear();
            iss.ignore(1);
        }
}
```

Output:

```
2.832
1.3067
1.678
-100
0.05
```

(see it running [here](http://ideone.com/TOi4UC))

Answer (score 3):

I have built up a more fine tuned version for this, that is able to skip invalid input character wise (without need to separate `double` numbers with whitespace characters):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    istringstream iss("2.832 1.3067 nana1.678 xxx.05 meh.ugh");
    double num = 0;
    while(iss >> num || !iss.eof()) {
        if(iss.fail()) {
            iss.clear();
            while(iss) {
                char dummy = iss.peek();
                if(std::isdigit(dummy) || dummy == '.') {
                    // Stop consuming invalid double characters
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    iss >> dummy; // Consume invalid double characters
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        cout << num << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output

```
 2.832
 1.3067
 1.678
 0.05
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/bueZmu)

Comment: This is good, but you may want to revise the while(1) loop. If there is an invalid double character at the end of the input then it will loop forever. eg http://ideone.com/3HSyxH

Comment: @Ben `while(iss)` may be?

Answer (score 3):

If you like concision - here's another option that (ab?)uses `&&` to get `cout` done only when a number's been parsed successfully, and when a number isn't parsed it uses the comma operator to be able to `clear()` stream error state inside the conditional before reading a character to be ignored...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("2.832 1.3067 nana1.678 x-1E2 xxx.05 meh.ugh");
    double num = 0;
    char ignored;
    while (iss >> num && std::cout << num << '\n' ||
           (iss.clear(), iss) >> ignored)
        ;
}
```

http://ideone.com/WvtvfU

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::istringstream::eof()` to *validate* input like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// remove white-space from each end of a std::string
inline std::string& trim(std::string& s, const char* t = " \t")
{
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(t) + 1);
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(t));
    return s;
}

// serial input
std::istringstream in1(R"~(
 2.34 3 3.f 3.d .75 0 wibble 
)~");

// line input
std::istringstream in2(R"~(
2.34
 3

3.f
3.d
.75
0
wibble 
)~");

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    // NOTE: This technique will not work if input is empty
    // or contains only white-space characters. Therefore
    // it is safe to use after a conditional extraction
    // operation >> but it is not reliable after std::getline()
    // without further checks.

    while(in1 >> input)
    {
        // input will not be empty and will not contain white-space.
        double d;
        if((std::istringstream(input) >> d >> std::ws).eof())
        {
            // d is a valid double
            std::cout << "d1: " << d << '\n';
        }
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    while(std::getline(in2, input))
    {
        // eliminate blank lines and lines
        // containing only white-space (trim())
        if(trim(input).empty())
            continue;

        // NOW this is safe to use

        double d;
        if((std::istringstream(input) >> d >> std::ws).eof())
        {
            // d is a valid double
            std::cout << "d2: " << d << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

This works because the `eof()` check ensures that *only* the double was entered and not garbage like `12d4`.

Comment: If `cin >> input` fails at eof, the `if` statement will evaluate `true` - easily fixed ala `if (cin >> input && (...)) ...`.

Comment: @TonyD You are totally right, it is important to remember this technique expects `input` to contain *something*.