# Wrong output when parsing the file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io

I am using the following code to parse a file.

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream infile("C:\\t50_20_1.td");

int num;
int pred;
int succ;

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while(iss >> num || !iss.eof()) {
        if(iss.fail()) {
            iss.clear();
            continue;
        } else {
            std::cout<<num<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

I am trying to print all the numbers in the following file

```
50
1   35   11   3  13       10  5       11  2       19  1       21  10       23  2       26  3       29  6       35  5       42  10       44  5    
2   3   12   8  7       15  12       19  9       24  6       27  13       29  7       32  8       34  6       35  8       37  9       38  12       39  9    
3   19   7   4  15       8  2       10  7       15  12       21  11       26  9       36  10    
4   35   8   5  13       7  7       10  8       13  13       20  1       21  5       44  1       48  15
```

But when the program ends I only get one number as output

```
50
```

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger. And note you're flushing your stream twice in a row with `endl << flush`.

Comment: `while(iss >> num || !iss.eof())` that doesn't look right

Comment: Note that `<<std::flush` is redundant `<<std::endl` already does this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It works well in [this context](http://ideone.com/BhVxSp). Was originally taken [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24520662/1413395)

Comment: I removed std::flush but I get the same output

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, That's not what the question's code does, though. If it fails a read, it just clears the flag and then tries to read what it just failed to read, over and over again.

Comment: @chris Of course, I know that. It was a misconception of the OP, and just a clarification from my side. I gave them the link to go figuring out how to read such kind of input.

Comment: I test your code it works fine ! you are using `cin.ignore()` in while loop so you need to press enter for seeing other numbers !

Comment: I got the same outpout, then i pressed enter, and enter and I got the remaining numbers...

Comment: @Worker is it still the file where you try to read a well defined sequence of process numbers followed by a variable number of communication parameters ?

Comment: @xyz thanks. Write your answer in the answers section and thanks for your help.

Comment: @Worker Also see [here please](http://ideone.com/X0Ozb3), I adapted your code a bit to simulate the file input, and it seems to work as expected for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you remove the **!iss.eof()** conditional as it is not necessary in the while loop. The Enter key must be pressed to continue to parse the following lines. Please see the following code. Also, I recommend you add "using namespace std" which implies std:: where necessary and can make the code more readable. Lastly, a few of the variables you are declared are not actually used and so they have been removed from the code below.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string line = "";
    ifstream infile("C:\\t50_20_1.td");
    int num = 0;

    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        while(iss >> num) {
            if(iss.fail()) {
                iss.clear();
                continue;
            } else {
                cout << num << endl;
            }
        }
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output (selected output only, all numbers are being outputted with the above code)

```
50
...
44
5
...
39
9
...
48
15
```