# not exiting while loop with cin as condition c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin, infinite

I know that this is a common question but i could not find any solution to this question without using vectors and ctrl + d/c. I have encounter a infinite while loop while using cin to get a unknown amount of integer. the while loop does not stop executing even after a enter in pressed. Thanks a lot!

```
while(cin >> num)
{
    num--;
    sizeB = 0;
    setB[sizeB] = num;
    sizeB++;
}
cin.ignore();
cin.clear();
```

Comment: Whitespace is ignored in formatted input operations. A newline is whitespace. Maybe you want to use `getline` instead?

Comment: If `num` is an integer than typing letters and pressing Enter will cause the loop to exit

Comment: @MarcoA the condition is `cin`.  (`operator>>` returns reference to `cin`). It's equivalent to doing `!cin.fail()`, i.e. check that neither end-of-file occurred, nor that something was typed which failed to be converted to the type of `num`.

Comment: @Zeta I am sorry i could not use getline as if i use get line it will be read all the values as one sentence.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not used to this usecase, that's definitely true (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/). To be precise `'does not return the same as member good, but the opposite of member fail'`

Comment: @MattMcNabb num is a int and enter did not cause the loop to exit thus i am troubled.

Comment: @Aurora_rainbow Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type?noredirect=1#comment37965807_24504582) helps you to understand.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'll delete mine, it's the first and might be the first thing someone picks up if he's in a hurry.

Comment: @Aurora_rainbow type in letters. like `"zod"` and press enter

Comment: @Aurora_rainbow consider  editing your question so that it actually asks a question

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so does that means that while(cin >> num) cant be use if there isnt a file/ text given?

Comment: @Aurora_rainbow No this means you should use `getline()` as suggested and parse and check for errors based on the given input string. If you have encountered an error or what ever your ending condition is, break the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use getline function to get data line-by-line, then read values via a stringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string line;
  while(getline(cin, line)) {
    stringstream str_stream(line);
    int num;
    while(str_stream >> num) {
      cout << "..." << num << "..." << endl;
    }
    cout << "----" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! because i did not learn stringstream before so i am a bit confuse but understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

`while` takes a bool argument. In your code, `cin >> num` returns an `istream&`, that is converted calling `istream::operator bool()` (and I'd guess evaluates to `true` if the stream is not closed)

read a string and convert it to int, break when the string is empty:

```
while (1) {
   std::string theString;
   std::getline(std::cin, theString);
   if (theString.empty())
      break;
   int num= atoi(theString.c_str());
   ...
}
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the (implicit) question yet.