# How to seperate integers from input string and convert them to type int to allow calculations on them

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, integer

As **Mehdi Algholipour** wrote i wanted to

1.Get string from input

2.Separate input to Integer numbers

3.Save them into Array

```
    cout << "Give me some integers separated with space";

    cin >> string;     // example input 10 210 300 510


    //..some code that seperate input to integer numbers and save them to Array


    //EXPECTED RESULT: Array[0]=10 Array[1]=210 etc...
```

Comment: `int array_of_ints[4]; for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array_of_ints); ++i) cin >> array_of_ints[i];` is that what you want?

Comment: Otherwise I don't get what you mean by array of integers then you say you want every string until space and put into array of strings, your question is not clear...

Comment: You could for instance use a solution like it is [proposed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24520662/1413395).

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it easier.

Comment: Do you mean you have a string that contains numbers and want to extract those numbers into an array of integers?

Comment: user9000 - yes !!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mean is:

1. Get `string` from input
2. Separate input to `Integer` numbers
3. Save them into `Array`

If this is your mean, try this code:

```
string str;
int arr[1000];  // I supposed 1000 is your Int Array size.
int number = 0, index = 0;

getline(cin, str);  // Get a line of string

for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++){   // Processing your str Array
    if (isdigit(str[i])){
        number *= 10;
        number += ((int)str[i] - '0');
    }
    else {
        arr[index++] = number;
        number = 0;
    }
}
arr[index] = number;    // for last element of your input

// Do something you want
```

Comment: @Jacob isdigit(int c) function need an argument that it is `ASCII Code` of an character. When given `ASCII Code` is an digit (0-9) it returns `true` otherwise `false`.

Comment: about your second question, lets suppose our input is `12`. This code firs reads `1` and sets `number *= 10; => number = 0 * 10 = 0; number += ((int)str[0] - '0'); => number = number + 1 = 1`. Next step, reads `2`. Now sets `number *= 10; => number = 1 * 10 = 10; number += ((int)str[1] - '0'); => number = number + 2 = 12`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::regex rgx("\\b\\d+\\b");

    std::string line;

    std::cout << "Please enter numbers separated by spaces and press enter:" << std::endl;

    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::sregex_iterator it(line.begin(), line.end(), rgx);
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    std::vector<int> values;
    std::transform(it, end, std::back_inserter(values), [](std::smatch s){ return std::stoi(s.str()); });

    for (int v : values)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringstream`:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);

stringstream ss(str);
vector<int> vec;

int Integer;
while(true)
{
    ss >> Integer;
    if(!ss)
        break;

    vec.push_back(Integer);
}
```

[live demo](http://ideone.com/cJrQiZ)

**Note:** You need to include following headers: `<string>`, `<sstream>`, `<vector>`