# Keep reading numbers until an empty input

Tags: c++

I'd like to make a program that keeps reading numbers until there is an empty input.
What I mean by that is the following:

```
12 <ENTER> 
24 <ENTER> 
<ENTER> 
Sum of these numbers is: 36
```

So far I've got this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

long double sum = 0, num = 0;
string junk;

int main(){
    cout << "Witaj w programie do liczenia sredniej!\n\n";
    while (true){
        while (cin >> num){ //stops when you input a char
            sum += num;
        }
        cin.clear();
        getline(cin, junk);
        cout << "\nSuma tych liczb to: " << sum << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works this way:

```
12<ENTER>
24<ENTER>
q<ENTER>
Sum of these numbers is: 36
```

If something is unclear let me know and I'll try to improve.
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Have a look here: [How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it). This may help for your problem also. Note that ENTER (`'\n'`) is actually ignored by `cin >> ...`, unless you change the standard delimitier.

Comment: I know it's ignored, I know also that u can change it using "noskipws" but I thought there is something that is able to recognize if there is nothing entered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code I cannot see checking of newline. See my code, it seems to work fine. Maybe it is solution which you are looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    string line;

    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        int tmp;

        if (ss >> tmp)
        {
            sum += tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nSuma tych liczb to: " << sum << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks Dakorn. I can't vote up - requires 15 reputation :(