# Why does this go into an infinite loop on not giving integer input?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    int n;
    label0:
    cout<<"Please an integer value\n";
    cin>>n;
    if ( cin.fail() )
    {
        cout<<"Please enter proper value\n";
        cin.clear();
        goto label0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"You entered"<<n<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly on giving an integer input but when I enter a non integer input, why does it go in an infinite loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it)

Comment: try `cin.ignore()` after `clear`

Comment: Works perfectly now.

Comment: That `goto` should be turned into a proper loop.