# Convert string Mac address to byte-array

Tags: c++, arrays, mac-address

I have a string (`std::string`) which contains a MAC address in C++, e.g.:

```
10:10:0F:A0:01:00
```

I need to convert it to an array of bytes (`unsigned char*`).

The bytes have to be written from left to right. Does anybody have a function or efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: haha @herohuyongtao.  i don't think that's what he means...

Comment: You can use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) along with the `hex` I/O manipulator, and use `:` as delimiter, to read in the equivalent numbers into a 6 byte array.

Comment: ok, sorry, I forgot to mention that the ":"-chars should be removed:-)

Comment: Do you have a code-example for the std::isstringstream with hex I/O manipulator and : as delimiter, I think it's really waht I need but can't find an example.

Comment: I actually have an [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type?noredirect=1#comment37965807_24504582) that shows how to skip bad input, should also work for your case. Though there are other possible solutions (e.g. `std::getline()` allows to specify an alternate delimiter).

Comment: Take care when reading in the numbers. Use an `int` in 1st place to read in, and cast the number to the target `uint8_t` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for necroposting, but just to help others who may still be searching for the answer, there is a standard C way that still can be used in C++ without any reinvention of the wheel. Just `man ether_aton` or click [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ether_aton.3.html).

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Worth the necropost.

Answer (score 0):

This'll work. You've tagged this as C++ so I've scrupulously avoided the shorter solution that's possible using the `sscanf` C method. `using namespace std` is used here only to shorten the quoted code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

main() {

  unsigned char octets[6];
  unsigned int value;
  char ignore;

  using namespace std;

  istringstream iss("10:10:0F:A0:01:00",istringstream::in);

  iss >> hex;

  for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    iss >> value >> ignore;
    octets[i]=value;
  }
  iss >> value;
  octets[5]=value;

  // validate

  for(int i=0;i<sizeof(octets)/sizeof(octets[0]);i++)
    cout << hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(octets[i]) << " ";

  cout << endl;
}
```