# Reading integers from a file with mixed integers, letters, and spaces C++

Tags: c++, sorting, fstream

This is a sort of self-imposed extra credit problem I'm adding to my current programming assignment which I finished a week early. The assignment involved reading in integers from a file with multiple integers per line, each separated by a space. This was achieved easily using `while(inFile >> val)` .

The challenge I put myself up to was to try and read integers from a file of mixed numbers and letters, pulling out all contiguous digits as separate integers composed of those digits. For examples if I was reading in the following line from a text file:

12f 356 48 r56 fs6879 57g 132e efw ddf312 323f

The values that would be read in (and stored) would be

**12**f **356** **48** r**56** fs**6879** **57**g **132**e efw ddf**312** **323**f

or

12, 356, 48, 56, 6879, 57, 132, 312, and 323

I've spent all afternoon digging through cplusplus.com and reading cover to cover the specifics of get, getline, cin etc. and I am unable to find an elegant solution for this. Every method I can deduce involves exhaustive reading in and storing of each character from the entire file into a container of some sort and then going through one element at a time and pulling out each digit.

My question is if there is a way to do this during the process of reading them in from a file; ie does the functionality of get, getline, cin and company support that complex of an operation?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read one character at a time and inspect it.  Have a variable that maintains the number currently being read, and a flag telling you if you are in the middle of processing a number.

If the current character is a digit then multiple the current number by 10 and add the digit to the number (and set the "processing a number" flag).

If the current character isn't a digit and you were in the middle of processing a number, you have reached the end of the number and should add it to your output.

Here is a simple such implementation:

```
std::vector<int> read_integers(std::istream & input)
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    int number = 0;
    bool have_number = false;

    char c;

    // Loop until reading fails.
    while (input.get(c)) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            // We have a digit.
            have_number = true;

            // Add the digit to the right of our number.  (No overflow check here!)
            number = number * 10 + (c - '0');
        } else if (have_number) {
            // It wasn't a digit and we started on a number, so we hit the end of it.
            numbers.push_back(number);
            have_number = false;
            number = 0;
        }
    }

    // Make sure if we ended with a number that we return it, too.
    if (have_number) { numbers.push_back(number); }

    return numbers;
}
```

([See a live demo](http://ideone.com/BoIEJR).)

Now you can do something like this to read all integers from standard input:

```
std::vector<int> numbers = read_integers(std::cin);
```

This will work equally well with an `std::ifstream`.

You might consider making the function a template where the argument specifies the numeric type to use -- this will allow you to (for example) switch to `long long int` without altering the function, if you know the file is going to contain large numbers that don't fit inside of an `int`.

Comment: That works perfectly thank you! My teacher has discouraged us from using vectors up until now so it didn't occur to me to try that.

Comment: @user3776749 "My teacher has discouraged us from using vectors" - lets pray that ends soon. With the possible exception of `std::basic_string`, you would be hard pressed to find a standard library template that is more frequently used by C++ engineers than `std::vector<>`. (and +1 on the answer, btw).

Comment: @user3776749 Np. Note the updated answer, which uses `input.get(c)` instead of `input >> c`.  The `>>` operator for `char` on input streams will skip over whitespace characters, which is not what you want.