# C++ Throwing istream specific errors when parsing a file

Tags: c++, exception, istream

Hi I have this line in my main method:

`std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Constituency>(inputFile), std::istream_iterator<Constituency>(), std::back_inserter(constits));`

This parses a file into a vector. I have overwritten the `std::istream <<` operator overload and am looking for ways to throw specific error messages if parsing fails. Here is the << operator overload:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& input, Constituency& constituency) {

    int num_neighbours;
    input >> num_neighbours;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> neighbours(num_neighbours);

    for(int i = 0; i < num_neighbours; i++) {
        try{
            input >> neighbours[i];
        } catch(...) {
            std::cout << "Error: Int Neighbour" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    try{
        input >> name;
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Error: Expected String Name" << std::endl;
    }

    constituency = Constituency(name, neighbours);

    return input;
}
```

The error messages don't get printed out. How can I change this so that if a string is encountered where an int is expected it throws and error and vice versa.

Comment: Segmentation fault is *not* a C++ exception and can't be caught by `try catch`.

Comment: @some[rpgrammerdude I dont want it to catch segmentation fault I want it to catch when it attempts to `input >> neighbours[i]` with a string when neighbours[i] is of type int

Comment: not quite clear `neighbours[i];` is always an `int`. Perhaps you want to read input as string and first check if it is an integer or not

Comment: @idclev463035818 guess that could work and then throw an exception to the main method if its not an int?

Comment: i think I understood what you want finally, there is a way to enable `cin` throw exceptions, but it is used so rare that I didnt find a good duplicate, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26187787/4117728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an input operation fails, a "failbit" is set on the stream.

You can check for this with an "if" statement:

```
input >> neighbours[i];
if (!input) {
   std::cout << "Error: Int Neighbour" << std::endl;
}
```

Or:

```
if (!(input >> neighbours[i])) {
   std::cout << "Error: Int Neighbour" << std::endl;
}
```

However, as well as `cout`ing, you're also going to need to do something with that bad input. If you're not planning to just "return", you will have to skip a line, or skip some number of bytes, or do whatever it is that you think is appropriate. Also clear the error state with `std::cout.clear()`, otherwise no further input operations will succeed.