# C++ mystical infinite loop

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ after previously coding with Java.  The code below takes input from the user and validates the input.  The first piece asks for the number of voters, which must be a positive number.  If I enter a negative number the program behaves as I expected.  It prints out the error message and asks for the input again.  However, if I enter any other character, such as any alphabet letter I get an infinite loop in the console, asking for input and printing the error message.  What am I doing wrong?

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct dataT {
    int numOfVoters = -1;
    float preSpread = -1;
    float votingError = -1;
};

void getUserInfo() {
    dataT data;
    while (data.numOfVoters == -1) {
        cout << "enter the number of voters" << endl;
        cin >> data.numOfVoters;
        if (data.numOfVoters <= 0) {
            data.numOfVoters = -1;
            cout << "Invalid entry, please enter a number larger than zero." << endl;
        }
    }
    while (data.votingError == -1) {
        cout << "enter the percentage spread between candidates" << endl;
        cin >> data.votingError;
        if (data.votingError <= 0 || data.votingError >= 1) {
            data.votingError = -1;
            cout << "Invalid entry. Enter a number between 0 to 1." << endl;
        }
    }
    while (data.preSpread == -1) {
        cout << "Enter the precentage spread between the two candidates." << endl;
        cin >> data.preSpread;
        if (data.preSpread <= 0 || data.preSpread >= 1) {
            data.preSpread = -1;
            cout << "Invalid input. Enter a number between 0 and 1." << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    getUserInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

Console:

```
enter the number of voters
f
Invalid entry, please enter a number larger than zero.
enter the number of voters
Invalid entry, please enter a number larger than zero.
enter the number of voters
Invalid entry, please enter a number larger than zero.
...
...
...
```

Comment: Your input failed. You never checked for input failing, just having an invalid value that you assume is meaningful after a failed input.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type?noredirect=1#comment37965807_24504582

Comment: in the first "WHILE" loop, u only check for negative number, and as long as it is not negative, you code will accept it, make sure do a cast to int

Comment: @chris, sorry for the novice question, but can you elaborate a bit on how I should check for input failing?

Comment: No need. There's a [FAQ entry](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#stream-input-failure).

Comment: @chris, thanks!  For future reference, can anyone explain why this question was down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `cin >> integervariable` but in cin there are character that cannot represent an integer, the input fails, `!cin` becomes true, and the character remain there until you don't reset the input state from the error and consume the wrong characters.

a proper check can be

```
while(integervariable has not good value)
{
    cout << "prompt the user: ";
    cin >> integervariable;
    if(!cin) //something wrong in the input format
    { 
       cin.clear(); //clear the error flag
       cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //discard the rubbish
       cout << "prompt error message \n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements are always `true`, you want something more like:

```
if (data.votingError < 0 || data.votingError > 1) {
    ...
```

then `data.votingError` can take on a value different from `-1` and exit your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::cin` object will check whether or not it is in a valid state every time it reads. If you enter a `char` where your program expects an `int`, then you'll "break" the input stream. All subsequent calls to `std::cin` will then be effectively skipped until you manually reset the input stream. When this happens, you'll never be able to set your values to anything other than `-1`, and your `if` statement always evaluates to true, causing an infinite loop.

As an aside, you can check for failure state by including `&& cin` in all of your tests. Input objects implicitly evaluate to `true` if the stream is in a valid state and to `false` if the stream is in a failure state instead.