# Smarter way to implement this switch statement

Tags: c++, cin

So I am trying to allow a user to make a selection but Im having issue. the following lines

```
cout << "\nWhat would you like to do? " << endl
    << "(1) Display the entire List" << endl
    << "(2) to exit" << endl;

getline(cin,answer);
answerint=stoi(answer);
switch (answerint) {
    case 1:
        showLIST(myLIst);
        break;
    case 2:
        return;
    default:
        cout << "\nPlease choose from the list";
   }
```

So this works fine if the user chooses a integer, but it barfs if a character is received. How can I make this less breakable?

Comment: perhaps avoid converting arbitrary input to an int? Or catch the thrown exception and handle it gracefully?

Comment: You need to check the values and make sure they are valid before you work with them.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type?noredirect=1#comment37965807_24504582

Comment: Im a bit novice to C++ so Im looking for a better practice if there is one or a way to make this more practical. @hosch250 what do you recommend to check for its validity?

Comment: Put the values in a `string` and iterate over each character to make sure there are no invalid characters in the string.  If there are, either remove them or make the use input another value.  Then, you can convert it to an `int`.

Comment: @hosch250 That's one of the worser advices. _@RobMcNeil_ Check out that linked Q&A I've mentioned.

Comment: OK, I agree that the Q/A you linked to is better advice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want something like this:

```
if (std::cin >> answerint) {
    switch (answerint) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Converting the integer directly from the stream puts the stream into failure state in case something different than an `int` is entered. You may want to add a manipulator to make sure there are no non-space characters on the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string answer;
int answerint;
while (std::getline(std::cin, answer))
{
    std::istringstream iss(answer);
    char c; // seek non-whitespace after the number?
    if (!(iss >> answerint) || (iss >> c))
        answerint = 0;
    switch (answerint)
    {
      ...as you had...
    }
}
```

The code above uses `getline` to ensure a complete line of text is parsed into `answer`, after which it creates a distinct `std::istringstream` from that single line.  That way, we can use `>>` knowing it won't skip over newlines are consume or wait for further input.

`if (!(iss >> answerint) || (iss >> c))` checks whether there isn't a number to parse into `answerint`, or after having parsed a number an additional non-whitespace character appears on the line.  For example, the line typed might have been `2r` - we'll consider that an error and reprompt for a selection, assigning `0` to `answerint` to ensure we reach the `default` label in the `switch`, thereby printing `cout << "\nPlease choose from the list";` which seems as appropriate for `2r` as for `99` or whatever....

Using `getline` and a separate `istringstream` this way, you can reliably attempt parsing of the next line of input from a known state.