# std::cin is not waiting for user input if the user input was non-int

Tags: c++, validation, input, io

std::cin does not wait for user input after the first iteration if the user input was non-int. It works if the inputted value was an int outside of the range (0 to 65535).

```
while(true)
{
    std::cout << "Number to convert to 16-bit binary: ";
    float decimal;
    std::cin >> decimal;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    if(decimal > 0 && decimal < 65536)
        return decimal;
    else
        std::cout << "Invalid input. Try again.\n";
}
```

Expected result:

> Number to convert to 16-bit binary: abc
>
> Invalid input. Try again. (ask user for input again)

Actual result:

> Number to convert to 16-bit binary: abc
>
> Invalid input. Try again.
>
> Number to convert to 16-bit binary: Invalid input. Try again.
>
> ...

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: When you don't input a decimal number, cin fails. Maybe check the state of cin after reading?

Comment: `std::cin.clear()` seems to be on the menu (as does actually checking the results of your IO in the first place. i.e. `if (std::cin >> decimal)` etc. One  of the many, many duplicates to this [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031338/clear-entire-line-from-cin-instead-of-one-character-at-a-time-when-the-user-ente).

Comment: @WhozCraig I read a little on std::cin.clear() and got the loop working. Thanks for your comment, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` is simply an instantiation of the `std::istream` class.

Values can be extracted from an `std::istream` object (a template specialisation for `std::basic_istream<char>`) - as you have shown in your question - using its overload for the `>>` operator with `float`s (in your case).

The `std::istream` object will extract characters from the stream - possibly skipping starting whitespace characters, and until a trailing whitespace character is encountered - and attempt to convert them to a `float` value (storing the result in your `decimal` variable).

However, if the conversion could not be performed, zero is stored inside the variable, and the `std::istream`'s `std::ios_base::failbit` is set.

Thanks to the conversion function to bool that has been defined for `std::basic_ios` (`std::istream`'s parent class), an `std::istream` object - such as `std::cin` - can be used in conditional expressions, as so:

```cpp
if (std::cin) {/* do this */}
```

Thus, you can simply check for a conversion error like so:

```cpp
float f;
std::cin >> f;
if (!std::cin) {
    // ... deal with error here
}
```

However, the more idiomatic way to do the above is:

```cpp
float f;
if (std::cin >> f) {
    // correct conversion, so can do stuff with f here
}
else {
    // conversion failed - deal with it here
}
```

The above works because all the `>>` overloads for `std::istream` return a reference to the `std::istream` object itself.

You can read up on all the `>>` overloads for `std::istream` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).