# Can't exit while true loop

Tags: c++

I'm working on this program and the while loop just keeps running forever. What could be the flaw in this code and how should I fix it?

I'm completely new to programming and C++, any help would be much appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    char pizzaSize, theEnd;
    double price;
    bool coupon;

    while (true) {


        cout << "What is the size of your pizza? Type l for large or m for medium.";
        cin >> pizzaSize;
        cout << "Do you have a $2 coupon? Type true for yes or false for no.";
        cin >> coupon;

        if (pizzaSize == 'l') { price = 12.99; }
        else if (pizzaSize == 'm') { price = 9.99; }

        if (coupon && pizzaSize == 'l') { price -= 2.00; }

        cout << "Price: " << price << endl << "Press 0 to quit or Enter to continue.";

        cin >> theEnd;

        if (theEnd == '0') { break; }
        
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here's what it looks like when the code is run
[image: Here's what it looks like when the code is run]

The point is getting the program to keep running until the user decides to quit by pressing 0, but for some reason it just doesn't work as expected...? Like by the time I send my user input to "Do you have a $2 coupon? Type true for yes or false for no.", it prints out the price and then instantly gets thrown into an infinite loop.

Sorry if I'm not clear enough

Comment: [How to read a bool using std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203441/how-to-read-a-bool-using-stdcin)

Comment: Side note you do not even need an "infinite loop" there is : `do ... while(theEnd != `0`);`

Comment: *"the while loop just keeps running forever."* -- Well, yeah? That's what `while (true)` means.

Comment: Looks like you should have at least some simple debugging in your example. Dump the values of all your variables at the end of each iteration. Find the first one (in the order that they are read from the user) that does not have the value you expect, and eliminate all I/O after reading that value (giving you a smaller [mre]).

Comment: @JaMiT They have a `break` statement that's supposed to end it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a bool using std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203441/how-to-read-a-bool-using-stdcin)

Comment: @Barmar I'm looking at the text and title of the question, which should do a better job describing the scenario than it currently does.

Comment: @JaMiT The title is just a brief summary. The question is in the text and code.

Comment: @Barmar *"The title is just a brief summary"* -- Correction: the title is (just) a **bad** brief summary. It should be improved. -- *"The question is in the text and code."* -- The question should be in the text. Relying on code to convey key information (rather than demonstrate key information) makes for a bad question that should be improved.

Comment: @JaMiT My comment was meant to describe the *role* of the title, I wasn't referring to this specific question. In general, you need to read the full question, not just the title, to understand what is being asked. Otherwise, titles will be unnecessarily long, e.g. "While loop keeps running forever even though it has a break statement". That's redundant, since that detail should be in the question text and/or code.

Comment: @Barmar *"Otherwise, titles will be unnecessarily long, e.g. 'While loop keeps running forever even though it has a break statement'."* -- I don't see that as particularly long. Other options -- which would succinctly summarize the scenario better -- include *"Why does while (true) skip cin when reading a bool"* (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56303342)) and *"std::cin is not waiting for user input"* (similar tp [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61310832)). -- *"That's redundant"* -- Good. I think titles should be redundant.

Comment: @Barmar *"In general, you need to read the full question, not just the title, to understand what is being asked."* -- I suspect we have different goals here. You are describing whether or not the question **can** be answered. (It can be, no argument.) In contrast my goal is improving the question to the point where it **should** be answered. Yes, the question is complete, but the presentation leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @JaMiT In my opinion, the purpose of the title is to distinguish it from other questions, it doesn't need much detail. As long as it's not something totally meaningless like "Help me fix my program", it doesn't impact the question quality much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> theEnd` is expecting either `0` or `1`, not `"true"` or `"false"`. If you give `cin` something it doesn't expect (such as feeding a non-number when trying to input into an `int`, or feeding something other than `0` or `1` into a `bool`), the [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) gets set, and you are not permitted to read anything from further from the stream.

To check for errors like this, you can use the stream in an `if` statement, as

```
if (cin) {
  // Everything is okay; continue
} else {
  // Something bad happened! Stop asking for input!
}
```

If you input `0` or `1`, your program will work as intended.