# C++ int function. How do I detect false when zero is a valid return value?

Tags: c++

I have a function that parses some input from std::cin and returns an integer value on success.  I need to detect, based on the return value, if something went wrong when parsing input.  Zero is a valid return.  What can I use to differentiate between valid zero and "bad input"?

If I need to post code as an example, just let me know. Thanks!

[EDIT]

```
int parseInput(){
    int calculatedValue = 0;
    bool parseOk = true;
    /* Parse cin for valid input.*/
    if (parseOk) {
        /* Perform calculation. Can be zero */
    }
    return calculatedValue; // Any integer is valid
}
```

Comment: Often errors are returned as negative values, it's a widely used de-facto convention. You could use an enum to describe the various possible errors.

Comment: _"If I need to post code as an example, just let me know"_ Yes, you should. As for your question, you can throw an exception for example or have a separate output parameter and return `bool`

Comment: You need to reserve a special integer for bad input

Comment: @tux3 And what if negative values are in range of allowed inputs as well?

Comment: You can probably test if (std::cin)

Comment: have you considered throwing an exception?

Comment: return -1 for error, >=0 for success

Comment: @thang What if negative values are valid return as already suggested

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ then I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @tux3 Well, the OP left that point unclear. In general `-1` is a valid input for `std::cin >> int_var;`

Comment: Using a sentinel value usually winds up being a bad idea. A negative value might not be valid today, but functionality tends to change over time. Someday it might become a perfectly valid value and, all of a sudden, some things don't seem to work anymore. Also, programmers tend to be lazy, if a function returns a value, they will tend to just use the value and not bother to check if it's in a valid range. At least by using `std::optional` or an exception, they are forced to acknowledge that there could have been an error. They may still ignore it, but they are aware of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an boolean flag for checking if something went wrong, it is common practice (for instance, Qt library uses it) to do something like:

```
int getIntegerStuffFromInput(bool & ok);
```

or

```
bool getIntegerStuffFromInput(int & value);
```

Comment: I would do just the other way round, seems more intuitive for me.

Comment: That's not common practice at all. It may be so in Qt, but not in other libraries I've used.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ agree, I would rather return the integer value by reference, like `bool getIntegerStuffFromInput(int & value)` but it is *equivalent* and I was thinking (I don't know why!) in  Qt string conversion functions

Comment: The second version forces you to create redundant local variables. This makes it impossible to use the function in chained calls and prevents const correctness.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Since when would the 1st version work in a _chained call_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You are right, at the of the day it suffers from the same problems.

Comment: This worked like a charm for my application.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This would be the perfect job for [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional). Your best alternative, with regards to notify at return value, is to implement a similar class.

Alternatively, you should really use an exception. Exceptions are made exactly to notify the user of your function that something went wrong.

Comment: `std::experimental::optional` now

Answer (score 1):

When you read numbers from `std::cin`, the most important thing is not to read directly into an `int`. Instead, you use `std::getline` to **read a whole line of input** into an `std::string`. This way you can detect wrong input much more easily.

Once the line has been entered, you convert the resulting `std::string` to an `int`.

```
std::string input_line;
std::getline(std::cin, input_line);
// input_line now contains a whole line of input
```

In C++11, you just use `std::stoi` for the conversion:

```
int const input = std::stoi(input_line);
```

This function will throw an exception if the string cannot be converted to an integer number.

In pre-C++11, you use `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream is(input_line);
int input = 0;
is >> input;
```

The following code then checks if the line could be correctly converted to an integer number or not:

```
if (!is)
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if(!(std::cin >> input)) { /* handle bad input*/ }` totally depends on (not further given) context IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Reading a whole line will make it easier to catch wrong input like "1 22" when "122" was intended. Granted, my examples do not show such sophisticated error handling, but reading whole lines is just better practice in general IMHO.

Comment: Well, I have to agree it gives a better possibility to check what exactly is going on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26027067/1413395

Answer (score 0):

> *"What can I use to differentiate between valid zero and "bad input"?"*

**You have basically three choices**

If you need to handle all integers as a valid return value:

1. Throw an exception, that can be handled outside from your function call
2. Have a dedicated output parameter passed by reference, and return `bool` from your function, `false` indicates *bad input*.

If negative integers aren't a valid return value:

Just return a negative value and test for `result < 0`.

Comment: May the anonymous downvoter just mind to explain, what's wrong with my answer?