# Accepting either a string or a number from a single input C++

Tags: c++

If I were to ask the user a question and the response can be either a string or an int, I would have to determine if it were an int or a string before I can pass the input to a variable right? How would I do that?

Comment: Strings are a superset of numbers, at least in terms of holding the data.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit -- `Isdigit()`

Comment: If you exclusively want `int`, you can use the `input bits

Comment: I'd say this answer leads you to one of the best viable approaches: [How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it). Anyway, considered that there are so many approaches available to solve your problem (dependent from more certain use cases), it's not possible to give a concise answer at all.

Comment: @jafar _"the `input bits "_ What are these? That's new to me. Please explain!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/

Comment: I'm kind of surprised no one has mentioned `std::stoi`.

Comment: From your question, if your program asks "how old are you?" is `20` or `twenty` correctly possible answers?

Comment: @jafar I much prefer http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail. But that's merely opinion  based, and you should extend about the actual behavior a bit more in your answer for my taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this provides for string and integer answers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int y;
    string answer;
    cout<<"how old are you ";
    getline(cin,answer);

    stringstream ss;
    ss<<answer;

    //check if its int
    if(ss>>y)
        cout<<"you are "<<y<< "(int)"<<endl;
    else    //its string
        cout<<"you are "<<answer<<" (string)"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"the `input bits "_ What are these? That's new to me. Please explain!

Answer (score 2):

The normal way is to read in a string, check if the string contains an integer, and then if it does, convert the contents to an integer.  The goal of the `if(inttest>>myint)` is to attempt to read into an integer. If it succeeds, the input-string must have been an integer. If it fails, it wasn't an integer.

```
std::mystring;
int myint;

std::cin >> mystring;
std::istringstream inttest(mystring);
if (inttest>>myint) {
    //it's an integer
    std::cout << myint;
} else {
    //it's a string
    std::cout << mystring;
}
```

The reason for the additional istringstream is that `cin >> var` eats the input, so if it fails to convert, it is already gone. Thus the need to cache the input locally, attempt to convert it, and if that failed then use the cached value as-is.

Comment: why there the need for an additional `istrtingstream`? I thought the result of `std:cin>>var` should be enough.

Comment: `cin >> var` eats the input, so if it fails to convert, it is already gone.  Thus the need to cache the input locally, attempt to convert it, and if that failed then use the cached value as-is.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work for me (maybe I'm doing it wrong)
`int main()
{
 string input;

 //get the input from the user
 cout << "Enter either an int or a string ";
 cin >> input;
 istringstream inttest(input);
 if (inttest>>input) {
     //it's an integer
  cout << "it's an int";
 } else {
     //it's a string
  cout << "it's a string";
 }
 

 return 0;
}`

Comment: @PierreGaboriau: the goal of `if(inttest>>myint)` is to attempt to read into an _integer_.  If it succeeds, the input-string must have been an integer.  If it fails, it wasn't an integer.  Your code there reads into a string instead of an integer, which always succeeds, because a string can read anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the input with [`string::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and then use the string as input [string stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/) to try to read a number.

```
bool got_string = true; 
string line;
int number;
if (getline(cin, line)) {  // if read is successful 
    istringstream str(line);
    if (str >> number)         // and if the format corresponds to a number
        got_string = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you accept. If the answer should be only an `int`, then you can test the result of `if(cin>>var)` (where `var` is `int`). If it is `false`, then the readout was un-successful, which means you din't introduced a valid `int`.

In other words, the stream "detects" whether its last operation was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is the best way to do this, but a comment on an existing answer caught my eye...

> `cin >> var` eats the input, so if it fails to convert, it is already gone. Thus the need to cache the input locally, attempt to convert it, and if that failed then use the cached value as-is. –  Remy Lebeau

...so I thought I'd show that it *is* sometimes possible to recover from a parsing error - resetting the `istream` so further input can be attempted.  Using this approach, you can first try to read an `int`, and if that fails read a word of text into a `std::string`.  It's important to do it that way because reading say `"46"` into a `std::string` works just fine so doesn't tell you it could have been parsed as an `int`, but reading `"fifty"` into an `int` fails then you know you'll have to try getting it into a `std::string`.

Though not relevant for inputting an age, more generally one negative with this approach is - well - negatives.  Trying to parse `"-five"` as an `int` will consume the `-` then fail, leaving only the `five` to be parsed as a `std::string`.  Depending on the type of stream in use, you may be able to record the stream position with [`.tellg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg), then if it fails restore the position with `seekg`.

Anyway, enough blabbing - here's some code, where I use one `std::istringstream` in place of `std::cin` so I can run it on `ideone.com` without manual input, but the point is that it doesn't need an *extra* `std::istringstream` with a copy of a line of input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void f(const char* p)
{
    std::istringstream iss(p);
    int num;
    if (iss >> num)
        std::cout << num << " (an int)\n";
    else
    {
        iss.clear(); // recover from parsing int failure above
        std::string word;
        if (iss >> word)
            std::cout << word << " (a string)\n";
    }
}   

int main()
{
    f("five");
    f("35");
}
```

Output:

```
five (a string)
35 (an int)
```

Available on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/mJAeTu)