# parsing a string to get an int

Tags: c++, string

I have to read in a string from std::cin in my program. 
The lines from cin are in the format of two numbers followed by a colon, another two numbers followed by a colon, and then a straight line. Then, the same string would be repeated. An example:

00:33:11|22:55:22

and then I would want two ints a and b to be:
a = 3311
b = 225522

I'm trying to find the best way to extract the numbers from the first numbers before the straight line and store that into an int, and do the same for the second set of numbers.

I'm a little unfamiliar with c++, but I have thought about making a for loop, storing characters into a char array, and then using atoi on that array. However, I feel that this method is not the most elegant of approaches. Any suggestions to this problem?

thanks

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You were too quick on the trigger. I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: this is indeed not a duplicate! the reason is because the string isn't inclusively integers.

Comment: @NeilKirk Probably. It's about parsing the numbers. Anyway even for this case there's a number of duplicates available from SO.

Comment: Are you familiar with the boost library?  Are you using C++03 or are you using a newer standard?

Comment: @DrewDormann i am not familiar with boost library, but i specifically can not use boost. i am also using c++11

Comment: I'm a little wary of this question, since you seem to know how to do it - but you want to judge which answer is "most elegant".  There are a broad number of approaches, but the most elegant one would be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @sg123456 Here are some useful hints how it can be done: [How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it)

Comment: I agree with @DrewDormann. I think it would be best to define "elegant", if you want to make it a beauty pageant it's not a good place. If by elegant you mean best in terms of time/space complexity it would be better. I also would understand the urge to write it in proper modern c++ idioms. It's hard if you are not familiar with it. Perhaps best way it to write something that works, and put it on codereview. At least it would show some effort rather than being possible to interpret as "Write me some code, i'll take the prettiest one."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::istringstream` and `std::getline()` to help you with that:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int timeStrToInt(const std::string &s)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    char colon1, colon2;
    int v1, v2, v3;

    if ((iss >> std::setw(2) >> v1 >> colon1 >> std::setw(2) >> v2 >> colon2 >> std::setw(2) >> v3) &&
        (colon1 == ':') && (colon2 == ':'))
    {
        return (v1 * 10000) + (v2 * 100) + v3;
    }

    // failed, return 0, throw an exception, do something...
}

void doSomething()
{
    //...

    std::string line = ...; // "00:33:11|22:55:22"

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string value;

    std::getline(iss, value, '|');
    int a = timeStrToInt(value);

    std::getline(iss, value);
    int b = timeStrToInt(value);

    //...
}
```

Personally, I would use `sscanf()` instead:

```
#include <cstdio>

std::string line = ...; // "00:33:11|22:55:22"

int v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6;
if (std::sscanf(line.c_str(), "%02d:%02d:%02d|%02d:%02d:%02d", &v1, &v2, &v3, &v4, &v5, &v6) == 6)
{
    int a = (v1 * 10000) + (v2 * 100) + v3;
    int b = (v4 * 10000) + (v5 * 100) + v6;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I really enjoyed this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try scanning in integers, and scanning and ignoring the separator characters. Then use some multiplication to get your number. In your case, try this:

```
int a;
char b;
int result = 0;
cin >> a;
result += a*10000;
cin >> b;
cin >> a;
result += a*100;
cin >> b;
cin >> a;
result += a;
```