# C++ getting floats out of long char array

Tags: c++, arrays, scanf

This is probably a rookie question, but I couldn't find the answer in the search.
I got a variable:
char buffer[ 128 ];
now I've made it's value through a search script, coming from a big file to:

"Density @ 15°C                 kg/m3           990.1       (  991.0 Max ).BR.Viscocity @50°C                cSt             355."

This is a specific line of 128 chars that I'm intrested in, more specifically the float "990.1". I need to get this out of all my files which is a bunch so getting the program to search for that specific text is not ok (I'll need to loop through a lot of files), it has to search for the first float. I've been trying with sscanf, but been stuck on it for a while now so I thought I'd ask.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you're using C++11, consider using regex.

Comment: Is it C or C++? you've tagged as both, which is probably wrong.

Comment: My bad, should have been only c++ :)

Comment: Here are some basic hints about parsing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Comment: if not using latest c++ use boost::regex

Answer (score 0):

If the float value you're looking for is **always** between `kg/m3` and  (space) you can use `strstr` to exctract the piece of string and then convert to float.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

```
char *start;
char *end;
double val;

start = strstr( buffer, "kg/m3 " );
start += 6;
end = strstr( start, " " );
*end = 0;

val = atof( start );
*end = ' ';
```

Note that I look for the termination space and convert to null termination character.

So `atof` parses buffer starting from `start` and stops after the last digit.

Later I restore the space to leave the original string unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input everybody. So I went with the comments answer of πάντα ῥεῖ by using parsing, mainly because of the whitespace giving **me** issues on Paolo's suggestion. This is what has worked out for me:

```
            float num;
            string dummy;
            istringstream iss( buffer );
            while( !iss.eof() && dummy != "(") 
            {
                iss >> num;
                if(iss.fail()) {

                    iss.clear();
                    iss >> dummy;
                    continue;
                }                   
            }
```