# Why does this code end up in an infinite loop, reading from std::cin

Tags: c++, loops, stdvector

Hi I try to create a input function for my function through vector.

However, I don't know why my input become infinite loop?

```
do {            
    cout << "Please enter the next number: ";
    cin >> num;
    number.push_back(num);
    cout << "Do you want to end? enter 0 to continue.";
    dec = NULL;
    cin >> dec;
} while(dec == 0);
```

Comment: if dec is not a pointer then you should not use `dec = NULL;`.  If you cant replace `NULL` with `nullptr` your code should be considered broken.

Comment: You should [add some concrete inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29633122/edit) given with your question, when your code shows this behavior.

Comment: To give more explanation why I've rolled back your question to it's original state, please follow the according discussion on [Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290240/should-i-rollback-the-ops-edits-if-they-just-replicate-my-answers-proposed-ch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I don't know why my input become infinite loop."*

The only reason I can imagine is, that any incorrect input sets `cin` to `fail` state. In this case (e.g. an invalid number was entered, or just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> was pressed) `cin` is set to `fail` state and your value in `dec` won't change evermore. Once `cin` is in `fail` state any subsequent input operations will fail respectively, and the subject for input won't be changed.

To be proof against such behavior, you have to `clear()` the `std::istream`'s state, and read up to a safe point, before proceeding (see also: [**How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it)):

```
do {
    cout << "Please enter the next number: ";
    if(cin >> num) {
        number.push_back(num);
    }
    else {
       cerr << "Invalid input, enter a number please." << std::endl;
       std::string dummy;  
       cin.clear();
       cin >> dummy;
    }
    cout << "Do you want to end? enter 0 to continue.";
    dec = -1;
    if(!(cin >> dec)) {
       std::string dummy;  
       cin.clear();
       cin >> dummy;
       break; // Escape from the loop if anything other than 0 was
              // typed in
    }
} while(dec == 0);
```

Here are three working demos with different inputs to end the loop:

[1st Input](http://ideone.com/pF5cwT):

```
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
```

<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[2nd Input](http://ideone.com/TZvI8H):

```
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
xyz
```

[3rd Input](http://ideone.com/NP6ShS)

```
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
42
```

---

The loop is finite, and output for all of the above is

```
1234
```

---

<sub>You should also note that I have changed `bool dec;` to `int dec;`, but that's probably a minor point.</sub>

Comment: @HuangElizabeth _"next line of code"_ I don't get what you mean?

Comment: There is a loop for output after my while function. If I press 0 to end the program. The program will not go to next loop for output. I have edit my post.

Comment: @HuangElizabeth Please have a look at my working demos at ideone.

Comment: @HuangElizabeth _"The program works now "_ You may consider accepting this answer by clicking the big white check mark at the left side.