# C++ stringstream value extraction

Tags: c++, stream, formatted-input

I am trying to extract values from `myString1` using `std::stringstream` like shown below:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string myString1 = "+50years";
  string myString2 = "+50years-4months+3weeks+5minutes";

  stringstream ss (myString1);

  char mathOperator;
  int value;
  string timeUnit;

  ss >> mathOperator >> value >> timeUnit;

  cout << "mathOperator: " << mathOperator << endl;
  cout << "value: " << value << endl;
  cout << "timeUnit: " << timeUnit << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
mathOperator: +
value: 50
timeUnit: years
```

In the output you can see me successfully extract the values I need, the math operator, the value and the time unit.

Is there a way to do the same with `myString2`? Perhaps in a loop? I can extract the math operator, the value, but the time unit simply extracts everything else, and I cannot think of a way to get around that. Much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that timeUnit is a string, so `>>` will extract anything until the first space, which you haven't in your string.

Alternatives:

- you could extract parts using getline(), which extracts strings until it finds a separator.  Unfortunately, you don't have one potential separator, but 2 (+ and -).
- you could opt for using regex directly on the string
- you could finally split the strings using [`find_first_of()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) and `substr()`.

As an illustration, here the example with regex:

```
  regex rg("([\\+-][0-9]+[A-Za-z]+)", regex::extended);
  smatch sm;
  while (regex_search(myString2, sm, rg)) {
      cout <<"Found:"<<sm[0]<<endl;
      myString2 = sm.suffix().str(); 
      //... process sstring sm[0]
  }
```

Here a [live demo](http://ideone.com/ePwgM4) applying your code to extract ALL the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could something more robust like `<regex>` like in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main () {
  std::regex e ("(\\+|\\-)((\\d)+)(years|months|weeks|minutes|seconds)");
  std::string str("+50years-4months+3weeks+5minutes");
  std::sregex_iterator next(str.begin(), str.end(), e);
  std::sregex_iterator end;
  while (next != end) {
    std::smatch match = *next;
    std::cout << "Expression: " << match.str() << "\n";
    std::cout << "  mathOperator : " << match[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  value        : " << match[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  timeUnit     : " << match[4] << std::endl;
    ++next;
  }
}
```

### Output:

```
Expression: +50years
  mathOperator : +
  value        : 50
  timeUnit     : years
Expression: -4months
  mathOperator : -
  value        : 4
  timeUnit     : months
Expression: +3weeks
  mathOperator : +
  value        : 3
  timeUnit     : weeks
Expression: +5minutes
  mathOperator : +
  value        : 5
  timeUnit     : minutes
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ede1f6b581806c31)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `getline` for the `timeUnit`, but since `getline` can take only one delimiter, I'd search the string separately for `mathOperator` and use that:

```
string myString2 = "+50years-4months+3weeks+5minutes";
stringstream ss (myString2);
size_t pos=0;

ss >> mathOperator;
do
  {
    cout << "mathOperator: " << mathOperator << endl;

    ss >> value;
    cout << "value: " << value << endl;

    pos = myString2.find_first_of("+-", pos+1);
    mathOperator = myString2[pos];
    getline(ss, timeUnit, mathOperator);
    cout << "timeUnit: " << timeUnit << endl;
  }
while(pos!=string::npos);
```