# c++ How to determine whether a string from an input file is int or str?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    string names[20];
    string temp;
    int vote=0;
    int votes[10];

    for(int i =0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        input>>temp;
        if (strcmp(temp,"9")>0)
        {
            names[i]=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to read in a file and store every name(ie. James Tylon) into a `string` array and when it detect an `int`, it will stop.
However when I use this approach, error comes out.

```
error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 
 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' 
 to 'const char *'
```

Comment: _`if (strcmp(temp,"9")>0)`_ sure?? What's the point of  `std::string` and not actually using it? Also have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it) please.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to use the [string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) method instead of strcmp ?

Comment: What do you want that `strcmp` call to do? Is "123a" a string or integer? What about "a23", or " 12z56"?

Comment: Note that you are actually storing every **word** by using `>>`, so name like `James Tylon` will be separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will check for a number:

```
if (temp.find_first_not_of ("0123456789") == std::string::npos ) {
     std::cout << "is an integer!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is "zz 9 plural z alpha" an int? That code would say yes.

Comment: @AlanStokes updated the answer

Comment: Is 99999999999999999999999999999 an `int`?

Comment: @AlanStokes I suppose user needs to test a number and not a C integer, anyways I changed int to integer

Comment: Yeah this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `strcmp` then you should supply it two `char *` parameters and not `std::string`. That causes the compilation error you mentioned.
You can fix it like that: `strcmp(temp.c_str(), "9")`.

Also according to your example I see that you expect an integer at the first char, that means that anything that starts with a letter and has a digit inside of it is a legal value which you classify as *string*. In this case you could test it by:

```
if (static_cast<unsigned>(temp[0] - '0') <= 9) 
{
    /* Digit detected */
}
```

Comment: Or if you want portability: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) to find whether the value is an `int` or not.

[Here](https://ideone.com/hriSPp) is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a[2] = {"this string contains integer 1423 and character", "100"} ;
    regex integer("(\\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+");

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(string); i++) {
        if (regex_match(a[i], integer)) {
            cout << a[i] << ": contains integer only\n";
        } else {
            cout << a[i] << ": doesn't contain integer only\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> this string contains integer 1423 and character: doesn't contain integer
>
> 100: contains integer