# Count the amount of integers in every line from file C++

Tags: c++

My task is to count the amount of integers in every line from a txt file in C++.

The file format is :

```
    Steve Road_43 St43 32 45 2 5 7 23 545

    John Road_21 Dt_4 3 4 5 12 31 0
```

Finally the format is < string string string int int int int.....int>
The problem is that the amount of integers in every line is different, so how can i know the amount of integers in every line ?

My code ->

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>


using namespace std ;




int main()
{

  string File_Name ,
         temp ;



  int counter_0 = 0 ;



  cout << " Please enter the File-Name :  " ;
  getline ( cin, File_Name ) ;
  cout << endl << endl << endl ;


  ifstream FP_1 ( File_Name ) ;


  if ( FP_1.is_open(  ) )
  {

      while ( ! FP_1.eof( ) )
      {

        getline ( FP_1, temp ) ;
        cout << temp;
        stringstream str ( temp ) ;

         int x ;

         while ( str >> x )              
         {
            counter_0 ++ ;
         }

        cout << " "  << counter_0 <<endl;
        counter_0 = 0;

      }

  }
  else
  {
      exit ( 1 ) ;
  }


  FP_1.close ( ) ;



 system ( " pause " ) ;
 }
```

counter_0 is always zero..does not count integers

Comment: Related [`while ( ! FP_1.eof( ) )`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Comment: Suggestion - parse the line into "words".  Then have a separate check to see if the word is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon `str >> x` sees a non `int` type in the input the state of `str` is set to `fail` and you never resume it.

Hence no numbers will be read, since the lines start with non numeric values.

You can consume the two non `int` values beforehand and read all of the `int` values afterwards:

```
     int x ;
     std::string dummy;

     str >> dummy >> dummy;

     while ( str >> x )              
     {
        counter_0 ++ ;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how str can ignore string type?

Comment: @Steve21 See my solution added in the answer. For a more detailed explanation see the link I've provided in my 2nd comment on your question.