# (C++)Could someone help me with getline from a string?

Tags: c++

I'm new to this community.

I got a program which get info from a .txt file then store it into a array for future use.However,when i try to get line from file with cities name,it didn't work that well.

Sameple for the line:

```
8175133 New York, New York, United States
7871900 Taipei, Taiwan
7785965 Kinshasa, Democratic Republic of the Congo
```

the point here is to get the weight(which are those long int) and the name of the cities(include the Country name .etc) then store them into a class named "Term" which has two variables "weight" and "query".Then store the "Term" class in a list.

My problem is,how can i do that?(get info from the file)
The way i did it was to get whole line (such as "7871900    Taipei, Taiwan")then try to use "(getline(iss,get_line,' ')" but it didn't work and give me "0" for most of the lines.

```
  Autocomplete Search_SL(10),Result_SL(k+1);
    while (!in_file.eof())
    {
        string weight;
        string query_LS;
        long weight_LS;
        string name;
        getline(in_file,name);
        istringstream iss(name);
        for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        {
            if (getline(iss,get_line,' '))
            {
                weight = get_line;
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    weight_LS = atoi(weight.c_str());
                    cout<< weight_LS<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    query_LS += weight;
                }
            }
        }
        if (query_LS != "")
        {    
            Term input_que(query_LS,weight_LS);
            Search_SL.insert(input_que);
            last++;
        }    
    }
```

Let me know if you guys have any questions on my question! :P Thank you!

PS: Here's a sample output(correct one):

```
Please input the search query(type "exit" to quit): 
Chic↵↵ 

 1. 2695598 Chicago, Illinois, United States 
 2. 577375 Chiclayo, Peru
 3. 86187 Chico, California, United States
```

I'm sure the rest of my program are right coz when i use other txt file which has line like "

```
 1. 5627187200  the 
 2. 509184100   at
```

it will works

Comment: Do `while(getline(in_file, buffer)) {...}` where `buffer` is a `std::string` which stores the contents of each line in the file. Parse each line around the comma and you're good to go

Comment: Thank you! But that's not really what i need in this case,my problems is how to divide the "weight" and the "name" into two different variables for each line i get from the file.

Comment: Is each weight and query in the file on separate lines?

Comment: no,one weight for one city,and one weight with one name makes one line,sorry for the confusion

Comment: You probably don't need to parse the integer value for `weight` since you can just use a formatted input provided by `operator>>`

Comment: Well,i did used >> but it didn't work,that's why i try a different approach

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After you get the line, try iterating through the istringstream elements (example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it)):

```
istringstream iss("2.832 1.3067 nana 1.678");
double num = 0;
while(iss >> num || !iss.eof()) {
    if(iss.fail()) {
        iss.clear();
        string dummy;
        iss >> dummy;
        continue;
    }
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

This will only return the numbers in the stringstream.

EDIT: Code to do this the other way around, i.e. get the strings instead of the numbers:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    istringstream iss("2.832 mike 1.3067 nana 1.678");
    double num = 0;
    while(iss >> num  || !iss.eof()) {
        if(iss.fail()) {
            iss.clear();
            string dummy;
            iss >> dummy;
            cout << dummy << endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it wont delete the numbers right?It works but it didn't help with my question! :3 Thank you though

Comment: ah sorry, i read that the other way around. Just swap double and string in the code above and it should do the trick, I'll update the answer

Comment: The second one didn't work,from my test,it would return all the stuff one by one whatever it's a string or long int :(

Comment: You're right, that's what I get for not compiling it haha. I updated the edit, it should work fine now :)

Comment: your solution worked ! :) but my program still has problem,i guess that's my work there.However,it has been an honer to discuss this problem with you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extraction `operator>>` of `stringstream`,which use a space as an input delimiter, to read the formatted long int value for the `weight`(no need to read this as string and convert to int) and you can then use `getline` to read the rest the line from the `stringstream`.

```
string query_LS;
long weight_LS;
string name;
while (in_file.peek() != EOF)
{
    getline(in_file,name);//read a line from the file
    istringstream iss(name);

    query_LS="";
    iss>>weight_LS;//read a formatted long integer,reads upto the space
    getline(iss,query_LS);//read the rest of the string     

    if (query_LS != "")
    {    
        Term input_que(query_LS,weight_LS);
        Search_SL.insert(input_que);
        last++;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the outline of a potential solution, untested so it may need some tweaking.

```
std::string buffer = "";
while(getline(in_file, buffer)) {
    // parse up to the first space (by checking characters in buffer)
    size_t count1 = 0;
    while (buffer.at(count1) != ' ' && count1 < buffer.size()) {
        ++count1;
    }
    // get substring of buffer up to first space occurrence, and convert to 
    // integral type to store in long variable
    long weight = atoi(buffer.substr(0,count1).c_str());

    // do similar parsing around the commas to get the city/country data...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the one immediate problem with your code is?

```
if (i == 1)    ==>   if (i == 0)
```

But I like to reuse what we have from the `std::`, specially in simple cases.

This is my "I too..." (untested):

```
struct Term {std::string query; long weight;};
... 
Term input{};
while(in_file>>input.weight && std::getline(in_file, input.query))
    if (!input.query.empty())
        Search_SL.insert(input);
```