# find numbers at string line c++

Tags: c++, string, line

```
#include<striang>
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line;
    cin>>line;
    istringstream iss(line);
    int i, count, numbers[100];
    count = 0;
    do
    {
        string sub;
        iss >> sub;

        numbers[count] = atoi(sub.c_str());
        count++;

    } while (iss);

    cout<<"Numbers"<<endl;

    for (i=0; i<count;i++)
      cout<<numbers[i]<<endl;

}
```

---

For the input

```
 1                   2      3  -4   8
```

I need the output

```
 1 2 3 -4 8
```

Comment: ?? you will get down voted if you don't edit your question. Please state **What** is your problem/error, **Where** and **How** are you trying to fix it. **Remove** all personal/unneeded information if you really want to get a good response

Comment: This example not my question's answer

Comment: Change `cin>>line;` to `getline(cin, line);`

Comment: work .. thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [@Jhonny Mopp's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575516/find-numbers-at-string-line-c#comment62638776_37575516) the primary problem is, that you don't read a whole line here:

```
cin>>line;
```

it just reads up to the next whitespace delimiter.

What you actually want is:

```
getline(cin, line);
```

This would read in the whole input until you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Regarding the rest of processing refer to that Q&A I formerly marked as duplicate:

[How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it)

Comment: @TaGiAsadullazadeh _"great"_ Not really. Take a look at your question score. I've just been answering because this would have been too long and poorly formatted as a comment. Please do a bit better research before asking the next time. There's plenty of [material to be found](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), why `cin >> line;` doesn't work like your expect it to do.