# Strtok in C++ abnormal behaviour

Tags: c++

I am trying to use strtok in C++ to get tokens of a string. But, I see that in one ur of 5 run the tokens being returned by function are incorrect. Can someone pls, suggest what can be the problem?

Sample code reproducing the issue I am facing:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
#define DEBUG(x) cout<<x<<endl;


void split(const string &s, const char* delim, vector<string> & v)
{
        DEBUG("Input string to split:"<<s);

        // to avoid modifying original string first duplicate the original string and return a char pointer then free the memory
        char * dup = strdup(s.c_str());
        DEBUG("dup is:"<<dup);
        int i=0;
        char* token = strtok(dup,delim);

        while(token != NULL)
        {
                DEBUG("token is:"<<string(token));
                v.push_back(string(token));
                // the call is treated as a subsequent calls to strtok:
                // the function continues from where it left in previous invocation
                token = strtok(NULL,delim);
        }
        free(dup);
}

int main()
{
        string a ="MOVC R1,R1,#434";

        vector<string> tokens;
        char delims[] = {' ',','};
        split(a,delims,tokens);
        return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
mayank@Mayank:~/Documents/practice$ ./a.out 
Input string to split:MOVC R1,R1,#434
dup is:MOVC R1,R1,#434
token is:MOVC
token is:R1
token is:R1
token is:#434

mayank@Mayank:~/Documents/practice$ ./a.out 
Input string to split:MOVC R1,R1,#434
dup is:MOVC R1,R1,#434
token is:MO
token is:C
token is:R1
token is:R1
token is:#434
```

As you can see in second run the tokens created are `MO C R1 R1 #434`  and not `MOVC R1 R1 #434`

I tried checking library code too but not able to figure out the mistake. Please help.

EDIT1: My gcc version is: `gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12)`

Comment: `strtok()` is one of the worst techniques you can choose.

Comment: Can you please suggest any other method? I want to split string using multiple delimiters. Also, I don't want to use boost library.

Comment: Here's some direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::string::find_first_of`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker - I used `endl` because in case program ends abnormally with Segmentation fault or something there may be chance that buffer was not cleared. So to clear buffer and be on safe side I used endl

Comment: @MayankJain - that's what `std::cerr` is for.

Comment: @krzaq why did you delete your answer? it proposes an alternate full C++ solution to `strtok` which is C and requires `strdup`, etc... bad. and you had figured out the problem too...

Comment: @PeteBecker - Got you.. Thanks for pointing the mistake

Comment: Can't speak for krzaq, @Jean-FrançoisFabre, but I didn't post anything because you beat me to the main bug and a google of "split string multiple delimiters c++" turned up half a dozen good SO answers already. Why pollute with more?

Comment: agreed. Also agreed that my answer is more useful to C users than to C++ users which should use "modern" split methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
char delims[] = {' ',','};
```

should be

```
char delims[] = " ,";
```

You're passing a list of chars instead of a `char *` bearing the list of delimiters to use, hence unexpected behaviour because `strtok` expects a 0-terminated string. In your case, `strtok` goes "in the woods" and tokenizes with anything after the declared array.