# Trying to separate string input from user into multiple integer variables

Tags: c++, string, integer, compare, substring

I am currently trying to take three, three digit weights separated by spaces input by a user and stored as a string variable. I want to separate the string variable into three separate integer variables to use for inequality comparisons later on. When I try to separate the string using substring functions I get an output of "abort trap: 6". I was just wondering if there's another way to separate the string into multiple integer variables.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main(){
string weight1str, weight2str, weight3str;
string weights;
int weight1, weight2, weight3;
cin >> weights;

weight1str = weights.substr(0,3);
weight1 = stoi(weight1str);
cout << weight1;

weight2str = weights.substr(5,7);
weight2 = stoi(weight2str);
cout << weight2;

    
    return 0;
}
```

Any help doing this using substr() would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Check `substr`'s documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) The second parameter doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.

Comment: `cin >> weights;` will only read up to the next whitespace character anyways.

Comment: If they're space separated, you can simply do `cin >> weight1 >> weight2 >> wieght3;`

Comment: I recommend adding a sample input and expected output that potential answerers can use as the base line of their answers. Its possible they can help you write a simple parser that doesn't need `substr` at all.

Comment: *I want to separate the string variable into three separate integer variables to use for inequality comparisons later on.* -- From what you describe, there is no need for `substr` to accomplish this.

Comment: _@Emerson_ Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it) helps you (no `substr()` used).