# Why are some programmers using string as an input and then converting it?

Tags: c++, string

I've recently came across this code in C++:

```
int main(){                                                                                                                  
    std::string a='0';  //I missed the quotes here anyways that wasn't 
                        //really necessary for the question                                                                                                       
    std::cout<<"Enter your number: ";                                                                                        
    getline(std::cin,a);                                                                                                     
    int ia=std::stoi(a);                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                             
    return 0;                                                                                                                
}
```

So why would someone write code like that, when you can write it like this:

```
int main(){                                                                                                                  
    int a=0;                                                                                                                 
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";                                                                                                
    cin>>a;                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                              
    return 0;                                                                                                                
}
```

(I'm using `using namespace std;` by the way)
Why write longer code like in the first example? Is it more efficient considering time and memory?

Comment: `std::string a=0;`? Where did you see this code exactly? If you can provide a link that would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Comment: @cigien this  derek banes guy yt video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tT8ICXAO_-4&t=626s

Comment: Thank you, but as always, add all relevant information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Although the code appears similar but not the same to the video you missed the quotes around the 0.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks but it doesn't really answer my question

Comment: No but it makes your code invalid / Undefined Behavior causing people to ask where you got this. It's illegal to pass a null pointer to the constructor of a std::string

Comment: @drescherjm my bad, fixed it

Comment: There are caveats when mixing in streaming operator and getline, and often is a source of problems when those nuances are not accounted for.  Often it is best (as in easiest) to stick with one or the other idiom.

Comment: Let's say you expect a number and the person enters "abc".  `cin >> x` fails to read it and puts the stream into a fail state.  To tell the user that they typed something wrong you need to know why it failed - but you don't know why it failed because you don't know what they typed.  If you read it as a string and then convert it you know which of the two things failed and your error message to the user is meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's more than one way to take this kind of input, and believe me, there are a multitude of weird, bizarre, if not just plain wrong ways to do it.

Reading into a `std::string` means you can do your own validation and surface errors where the conversion failed, or if the input was unexpectedly long or short.

If you read into an `int` you *will* get an `int` but it can obscure errors on input meaning you have fewer opportunities to provide feedback about conversion issues.

For example, with the `std::cin >> a` method you can input "lol" and you get back `0` which glosses over the fact that what you put in is total trash.

This is why it's often advantageous to read in a whole line into a `std::string` and do your own parsing, like checking with a regular expression that the format is correct before converting, otherwise surfacing errors.

Comment: Also, `std::cin >> a >> b;` for two ints, `a` will get set to 0 for the `lol`, but `b` will be the old value or still uninitialized, if it hadn't been initialized yet.  That one bit me years back.

Comment: @Eljay: with an input of `lol` neither a nor b will be modified -- a is 0 in this case (only) because it was previously initialized to 0.

Comment: @ChrisDodd • `a` will be guaranteed to be set to `0`.  `b` (because the stream is in a bad state) will not be (re)set to anything.