# Best substitute for goto in C++ as beginner for use in text-based RPG

Tags: c++, text, goto

I am very new to C++ and have decided to start with a basic text based RPG. I have been using this site as a reference; https://levelskip.com/classic/Make-a-Text-Based-Game#gid=ci026bcb5e50052568&pid=make-a-text-based-game-MTc0NDU2NjE2MjQ1MDc3MzUy

```
system("cls");
int choiceOne_Path;
cout << "# What would you like to do?" << endl;
cout << "\t >> Enter '1' to follow the Chief?" << endl;
cout << "\t >> Enter '2' to find your own path?" << endl;
retry:
cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
cin >> choiceOne_Path;
if(choiceOne_Path == 1)
{
    cout << "\n!!!----------------------Chapter One: Escape----------------------!!!" << endl;
    cout << "\nYou: Where are we going?" << endl;
    cout << "Chief: Soon you will know. Just follow me." << endl;
    cout << "# You run behind the chief." << endl;
}
else if(choiceOne_Path == 2)
{
    cout << "\n!!!----------------------Chapter One: Escape----------------------!!!" << endl;
    cout << "\nYou: I am going to find a way out!" << endl;
    cout << "Chief: You are insane. You will get killed out there." << endl;
    cout << "You: I have my secrets and I know my way out." << endl;
    cout << "# You jump over the nearby broken fence" << endl;
    cout << "# and run off towards the City Wall." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "You are doing it wrong, warrior! Press either '1' or '2', nothing else!" << endl;
    goto retry;
}
cout << "\n----------------------Press any key to continue----------------------" << endl;
_getch();
```

This is the code that the site shows as a reference but I have had some issues with it. Primarily with the "goto" command only working for incorrectly inputted *integers*. If you enter a letter character there, it makes an infinite loop instead.

During my search for a solution to the problem I found a great deal of animus towards the "goto" function. Modern code has essentially refuted it's use as I understand it. So at this point I am looking for a different function that can perform that task of redoing the cin function upon inputting an unusable character.

I am entirely willing to use a completely different structure or system if there isn't a natural replacement for that command in this context.

Comment: A loop maybe?!? Use certain ending conditions, and / or `break` and `continue` to control the loops execution. And here's an idiomatic solution for your particular problem btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Comment: Not working for "incorrectly input integers" has nothing to do with use of `goto` or the debate over what it is suitable for.   It has everything to do with what conditions your code checks for, how it identifies errors, and how it handles any errors it identifies.   Your code is assuming an integer is "correctly" entered, and not checking at all for cases where "incorrect" input is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Best substitute for goto
>
> ```
> retry:
> // accept input
> if (/* input predicate */)
> {
>     // ...
> }
> else
> {
>     // ...
>     goto retry;
> }
> ```

That's what we in the trade call a "loop". Any flavor of loop structure is fine for this example, but this is a rare case where do-while is nice. A direct transformation:

```
do
{
    // accept input
    if (/* input predicate */)
    {
        // ...
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
} while(true);
```

Comment: Just changing the code to a loop won't fix the problem that the OP actually describes.