# iam writing a integer check in c++ language

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i wrote a function that check if the variable is integer or not but if I put double or float it give me that it`s integer can anyone help me

```
    bool check(int a) {
    if (a == (int)a) {

        cout << "integer" << endl;
        
    }
    else {
        cout << "not integer" << endl;
    }
    return 1 ;
}

void main() {
    int a;
    cout << "enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    check(a);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/how-to-test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type-and-skip-it

Comment: `a` is *always* an integer, because you defined it as `int` variable in both places. What kind of input do you expect user to provide?

Comment: The general gist of the input problem: a floating point number is a valid integer right up to the decimal point. The parser stops at the ., calls the function on what it read, and leaves the . and fractional portion in the stream for the program do deal with in the future.

Comment: Note that the function in the question is a non-portable way of writing the standard-library function [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha).

Comment: I rolled back last edit because it was completely changing the question. Don't do that, in particular when there is already an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are taking in an integer value as an argument:

```
bool check(int a) // int a
```

So for example, if you pass in `3.12` into `check()`, then it will get converted to `3`. That's why:

```
a == (int)a
```

.. will mean:

```
3 == (int)3 // true
```

..while to get the correct result, it should be:

```
3.12 == (int)3 // false
```

So to fix your issue, just change the parameter type:

```
bool check(double a)
```

..and also the input variable type:

```
double a;
```

### Samples:

```
enter a number
3
integer
```

```
enter a number
3.12
not integer
```

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: It would be better if you'd ask a new question instead of editing your initial one to a different question.